# Creating a C# List with a local DateTime value from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, utc

I'm trying to create a list based on this XML data:  http://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.xml

I so far have:

```
private List<News> newsList;

newsList = new List<News>();

public class News
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public DateTime date { get; set; }
            public DateTime time { get; set; }
            public DateTime localDateTime { get; set; }
            public string impact { get; set; }
        }

        public void getNews()
        {
            String URLString = "http://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.xml";

            var doc = XDocument.Load(URLString);
            newsList = doc.Root
                .Descendants("event")
                .Select(node => new News
                {
                    title = node.Element("title").Value,
                    country = node.Element("country").Value,
                    date = DateTime.ParseExact(node.Element("date").Value, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    time = DateTime.Parse(node.Element("time").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    impact = node.Element("impact").Value
                })
                .ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < newsList.Count; i++)
            {
                Print(i + " | Title: " + newsList[i].title);
                Print(i + " | Country: " + newsList[i].country);
                Print(i + " | Date: " + newsList[i].date.Date);
                Print(i + " | Time: " + newsList[i].time.TimeOfDay);
                Print(i + " | Impact: " + newsList[i].impact);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting data into the list fine, and it is outputting fine.

What I'm struggling to achieve is how to convert the date and time fields from the XML into a 'localDateTime' in my list.

The XML date & time is in UTC and I want my list to store a single value that combines both the UTC date & time fields into a single local DateTime field.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Fix the XML file. Or don't use that source. Dates and times are serialized to XML based on specific standards and that string file doesn't follow them. In fact, it's actually trying to break them. `is in UTC` you don't know that. In fact you can't even know what those strings in the date tags are. Someone went to great lengths to store the values in a way that can't be parsed. That's why all those `CDATA` sections are used - to prevent parsers from complaining. You have no idea what `05-08-2022` is: May 8 or August 5?

Comment: In any case the correct type to represent the time of day is TimeSpan, not DateTime. If you want to parse those string fields as time use `TimeSpan.Parse`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't own the XML and am ok to work on the assumption that it is UTC based on my experience with the data.  Based on that, any suggestions to help me achieve my conversion to a local datetime?

Comment: Using TimeSpan for time, you can add TimeSpan to DateTime to create new DateTime.

Comment: You can add the time to the date.  Try : DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("05-13-2022");
            DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("2:00pm");
            DateTime localDateTime = date.Add(time.TimeOfDay);